# Facebook Likebox Plugin "show posts" tries to load posts which dont exist

Tags: facebook, loading, posts

there is a problem with the facebook like box. Tested on other websites, too!
If you scroll down all the posts there is a loading bar. It tries to load older posts. But on my facebook site are only 3 posts...
So the Website starts getting buggy and get problems with java and simple css comands.

Can I prevent the loading bar?
Are there other solutions?

Im using Chrome!

[Example](http://www.main-webdesign.com/projekte/jazzsalon/test.html)

You can get the code from this url.

When you turn up and down the scrollbar 5 or a few more times the bar becomes to get laggy like the menu...

Comment: You need to be more specific - more description, your code, screen shots etc.

Comment: Added a link! greetings